# Scaling equation for map so that scaling keeps user select center - Flash

Tags: dictionary, mapping, actionscript-2

ingredients:

```
- one vector map
- one masked viewing area
- one slider taking the map from 100% to 600%
- map is draggable
- map movieclip center is the top left of the movieclip
```

Let's say you zoom in, you drag the map so that the bottom right quadrant is in the viewing area, then you zoom out.

The problem:
Because the "center" of the map is the top left corner of the movie clip, scaling happens from that point. How can I keep the center point (while scaling) as the point which is centered on the view area?

Comment: I think your question is to difficult to answer. I suggest you rephrase your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Right after you scale you map, you could reposition the map so it's center matches the masks center.

```
//assuming map is the name of your map clip, and mapMask the name of the mask
map.x = mapMask.x + mapMask.width * .5 - map.width * .5;
map.y = mapMask.y + mapMask.height * .5 - map.height * .5;
```

This should work as the mask will always be larger than the mask.

Goodluck!